# Ajax query url (SharePoint App)

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint, crm

I am working on showing data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM into SharePoint.  I already have the OData connection setup and it does show data and my version 1 of the SharePoint app is working in my dev environment (meaning it is showing some data).

Here is a link to the site with the instructions I followed: 
[CRM and SharePoint via BCS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2013/05/13/connecting-sharepoint-online-and-crm-online-using-bcs-2013-edition.aspx#10590673)

This is for CRM Online 2015 and SharePoint 2013 Online (Dev environment).  As I stated I do have 100 items appearing in my table based on the `$select=` statement in the url.  But the url is not getting all the column heads, so columns that do appear in the odata service are returned as not existing when added the the query url.  Here is the URL right now:

```
        init: function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.surlWeb +
      "_api/lists/getbytitle('OpportunitySet')/items?$select=BdcIdentity,Name,StateCode,StatusCode,CreatedOn,OwnerId", //,ContactId,AccountId,OwnerId
            headers:
            {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose, */*",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: this.showItems
        });
    },
```

The list item in the url `OwnerId` is valid in the Odata service but returns as `"The field or property 'OwnerId' does not exist."`

Here is a copy of how the `properties` appear in RAW form from the OData connection:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:ActualCloseDate m:type="Edm.DateTime"</d:ActualCloseDate>
    <d:ActualValue m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:ActualValue>
    <d:ActualValue_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:ActualValue_Base>
    <d:CloseProbability m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:CloseProbability>
    <d:CreatedOn m:type="Edm.DateTime"></d:CreatedOn>
    <d:Description m:null="true" />
    <d:DiscountAmount m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
    <d:DiscountAmount_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
    <d:DiscountPercentage m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
    <d:EstimatedCloseDate m:type="Edm.DateTime"></d:EstimatedCloseDate>
    <d:EstimatedValue m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:EstimatedValue>
    <d:EstimatedValue_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:EstimatedValue_Base>
    <d:ExchangeRate m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:ExchangeRate>
    <d:FreightAmount m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
    <d:FreightAmount_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
    <d:ImportSequenceNumber m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:ImportSequenceNumber>
    <d:IsRevenueSystemCalculated m:type="Edm.Boolean"></d:IsRevenueSystemCalculated>
    <d:ModifiedOn m:type="Edm.DateTime"></d:ModifiedOn>
    <d:Name></d:Name>
    <d:OpportunityId m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:OpportunityId>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
    <d:OpportunityRatingCode m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:OpportunityRatingCode>
    <d:OverriddenCreatedOn m:type="Edm.DateTime"></d:OverriddenCreatedOn>
    <d:ParticipatesInWorkflow m:type="Edm.Boolean"></d:ParticipatesInWorkflow>
    <d:PricingErrorCode m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:PricingErrorCode>
    <d:PriorityCode m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:PriorityCode>
    <d:SalesStageCode m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:SalesStageCode>
    <d:StateCode m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:StateCode>
    <d:StatusCode m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:StatusCode>
    <d:StepId m:type="Edm.Guid" m:null="true" />
    <d:StepName m:null="true" />
    <d:TimeZoneRuleVersionNumber m:type="Edm.Int32"></d:TimeZoneRuleVersionNumber>
    <d:TotalAmount m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalAmount>
    <d:TotalAmount_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalAmount_Base>
    <d:TotalAmountLessFreight m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalAmountLessFreight>
    <d:TotalAmountLessFreight_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalAmountLessFreight_Base>
    <d:TotalDiscountAmount m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalDiscountAmount>
    <d:TotalDiscountAmount_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalDiscountAmount_Base>
    <d:TotalLineItemAmount m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalLineItemAmount>
    <d:TotalLineItemAmount_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalLineItemAmount_Base>
    <d:TotalLineItemDiscountAmount m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalLineItemDiscountAmount>
    <d:TotalLineItemDiscountAmount_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalLineItemDiscountAmount_Base>
    <d:TotalTax m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalTax>
    <d:TotalTax_Base m:type="Edm.Decimal"></d:TotalTax_Base>
    <d:UTCConversionTimeZoneCode m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true" />
    <d:VersionNumber m:type="Edm.Int64" m:null="true" />
    <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
    <d:AccountId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:CampaignId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:ContactId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:CreatedBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:CreatedBy>
    <d:CreatedOnBehalfBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:CustomerId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:CustomerId>
    <d:ModifiedBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:ModifiedBy>
    <d:ModifiedOnBehalfBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:msa_partneroppid m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:OriginatingLeadId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:OwnerId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:OwnerId>
    <d:OwningBusinessUnit m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name m:null="true" />
    </d:OwningBusinessUnit>
    <d:OwningTeam m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:OwningUser m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name m:null="true" />
    </d:OwningUser>
    <d:PriceLevelId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:TransactionCurrencyId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:TransactionCurrencyId>
```

This is a blank property.  From my research I found that anything after `<d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>` is ignored.  Those items would be:

```
<d:AccountId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:CampaignId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:ContactId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:CreatedBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:CreatedBy>
    <d:CreatedOnBehalfBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:CustomerId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:CustomerId>
    <d:ModifiedBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:ModifiedBy>
    <d:ModifiedOnBehalfBy m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:msa_partneroppid m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:OriginatingLeadId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:OwnerId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:OwnerId>
    <d:OwningBusinessUnit m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name m:null="true" />
    </d:OwningBusinessUnit>
    <d:OwningTeam m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:OwningUser m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name m:null="true" />
    </d:OwningUser>
    <d:PriceLevelId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference" m:null="true" />
    <d:TransactionCurrencyId m:type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid"></d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName></d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name></d:Name>
    </d:TransactionCurrencyId>
```

How do I overcome this and have the ability to access this information via my query url?  Mainly I am looking at accessing `OwnerId` and need to get the `name` part of that object.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$select` query, if you have the column name as `Owner` then change your query to `Owner/Id`, as the select query works the same as the `$expand`.

Comment: I don't follow as my `$select` already has `OwnerId` in it: `$select=BdcIdentity,Name,StateCode,StatusCode,CreatedOn,OwnerId"`

Comment: I am sorry I reread your comment.  I will give it a shot and report back.